# How to add the latest change to a commit that is not the latest, using git commit -m --amend?

Tags: bash, git, github, version-control, git-commit

I made 2 commits in git, namely "version 1" and "version 2". And after that i made another change to the code and used git commit -m "version 1" --amend. I thought it would add the new change to version 1 but it changed the name of version 2 commit message from "version 2" to "version 1" and added the new change to it instead. so, now i have two version 1 commits. But i wanted to add the new changes to the original version 1. How do i do that and how do i undo this --amend? Please explain.

```
before changes

git log

commit hash
   version 2
commit hash
   version 1

after changes

git commit -m "version 1" --amend

git log

commit hash
   version 1 (This is where the new changes happened)
commit hash
   version 1 (I want it to go here)
```

Comment: `-m` only specifies what the commit message will be; it doesn't select a target commit.

Answer (score 0):

To put your new changes into the bottom commit, you must make a new commit, say "Version 1 Amend", and then do an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3   # interactively rebase three commits
```

In the editor, reorder the commits in the order you want. Say we have:

```
pick 19df34d Version 1
pick 437ca9e Version 2
pick 6503d73 Version 1 Amend
```

Reorder them like this:

```
pick 19df34d Version 1
pick 6503d73 Version 1 Amend
pick 437ca9e Version 2
```

Then change the second `pick` to `squash` or `fixup`. (Read up on the difference, or experiment).

```
pick 19df34d Version 1
squash 6503d73 Version 1 Amend
pick 437ca9e Version 2
```

Then save and exit. If there are no conflicts it will be done; otherwise you will have to learn how to resolve conflicts in a cherry pick.

The above workflow can be slightly automated by using `git commit --fixup <hash>` or `git commit --squash <hash>` and then using `git rebase -i --autosquash`.

You can configure `git` so that `git rebase -i` implies `--autosquash`; it is useful to do that.

When committing the third commit, we would do this:

```
git commit --fixup HEAD^
```

All this does is generate a commit message which looks something like:

```
pick 19df34d Version 1
fixup 6503d73 fixup! Version 1
pick 437ca9e Version 2
```

The autosquash logic does the editing for you, rearranging the fixup/squash commits after their targets and setting up the commands.

Interactive rebasing, autosquash and conflict resolution in rebasing/cherry-picking are fundamental Git skills that require study and practice.